# Computer Lags/Freezes after a while desktop black screens

Tags: memory, graphics-card, freeze

This has happened for a while now.

If i leave my computer on over night or something I'll start to get memory errors (close programs to prevent information less) and also lags when accessing files and programs even when there are no processes taking up much usage.

It also will eventually mean i have to restart the PC since the whole desktop goes black, icons disappear and many artefacts appear. My computer is in a very hot room so which i cant ventilate it very well. Although i have a top fan, fans inside the case and also a good cpu cooler.

I am thinking it is either the GPU failing (ATI Raedeon 5850) or the RAM (Generic Corsair 2x4GB)

Could someone help me to identify which is the failing hardware?

Thanks

Comment: OS? it sounds like Windows to me. If this is the case I'd say check your Virtual Memory settings under Advanced of system properties. Set to System managed. Check if programs are leaking RAM causing you to fill what RAM you have.

Comment: Windows 7 64Bit

Answer (score 0):

I have my acer 4820-TG with ATI Raedon 5650 and got the same problem. I just tried to update the drivers and got everything perfect. Previously, My graphics card's switching problem made the whole screen goes blank and even my laptop hands and suddenly restarts which prevents me to save any open files. 
Also due to graphics card, many a times, my windows explorer crashes. 
I just tried to update the latest graphics card drivers and the PCI drivers from intel and now everything got fine.

Comment: even auto-switching technique of graphic card take down my ubuntu operating system. It is really a mess

Comment: I updated the driver but it didn't fix anything. Photoshop said "problems with display driver temporarily disabled"

Answer (score 0):

Testing?

For Ram, download [The ISO of Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/).  Burn a disc from the ISO, boot to it and let it run for a few hours.  If your Ram is bad, you will know from the abundance of red on the otherwise cool blue screen.

For your video card, download [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) and install.  Then run a benchmark.  I would not recommend stress testing it until AFTER you see if it can handle a simple benchmark.  You will be able to observe frame rates and temperatures while you are testing.  If there is an issue, it will develop soon enough... most probably during the short benchmark.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DratI.jpg

Comment: OUCH!  That's too hot.  Like... 20C too hot.  I noticed the fan was spinning at 53% though.  You can try ATI Tray Tools to manually crank your fan up to 100% and see if you can bring the temp down to around 70C or so, but I don't think you will be able to.  Good frame rate though, especially for that temp.

Comment: Do you think the GPU is unstable?

Comment: @tom possibly, yes.  You can stress test it (the fur mark bench test that's continuous) and see how long it goes until it fails.  I believe it would, but I could and can be wrong.  Some of the problems you describe initially in your question relate directly to a failing video card.  It could even be the VRAM on the card... getting too hot and failing instead of the GPU.